# Deploy C# Windows Application with Crystal Report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I really need to help my client which wants a complete application within this week. But I am stuck with a *Crystal Report* error. If you need more details from me, I can provide them for you.

The program is working fine on my PC after excuting the setup, but when I put it on my other PC, it shows the following error.

See the end of this message for details of invoking Just-In-Time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

This is the ************** Exception Text **************

> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument' threw an exception. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {4DB2E2BB-78E6-4AEA-BEFB-FDAAB610FD1B} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
>          at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument..cctor()
>          --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>          at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument..ctor()
>          at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportClass..ctor()
>          at UserManagmentSystem.Report.DisplayReport..ctor()
>          at UserManagmentSystem.UserManagment.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

These are the ************** Loaded Assemblies **************

> System
>           Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
>           Win32 Version: 4.6.1055.0 built by: NETFXREL2
>           CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
>       ----------------------------------------
>       CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms
>           Assembly Version: 13.0.3500.0
>           Win32 Version: 13.0.23.2819
>           CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL  /CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms/13.0.3500.0__692fbea5521e1304  /CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.dll
>       ----------------------------------------
>       CrystalDecisions.Shared
>           Assembly Version: 13.0.3500.0
>           Win32 Version: 13.0.23.2819
>           CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/CrystalDecisions.Shared/13.0.3500.0__692fbea5521e1304/CrystalDecisions.Shared.dll
>       ----------------------------------------
>       CrystalDecisions.ReportSource
>           Assembly Version: 13.0.3500.0
>           Win32 Version: 13.0.23.2819
>           CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/CrystalDecisions.ReportSource/13.0.3500.0__692fbea5521e1304/CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.dll
>       ----------------------------------------
>       System.Web
>           Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
>           Win32 Version: 4.6.1055.0 built by: NETFXREL2
>           CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.Web/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Web.dll
>       ----------------------------------------
>       log4net
>           Assembly Version: 1.2.10.0
>           Win32 Version: 1.2.10.0
>           CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_32/log4net/1.2.10.0__692fbea5521e1304/log4net.dll
>       ----------------------------------------
>       CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine
>           Assembly Version: 13.0.3500.0
>           Win32 Version: 13.0.23.2819
>           CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine/13.0.3500.0__692fbea5521e1304/CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll
>       ----------------------------------------
>       CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommLayer
>           Assembly Version: 13.0.3500.0
>           Win32 Version: 13.0.23.2819
>           CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommLayer/13.0.3500.0__692fbea5521e1304/CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommLayer.dll
>       ----------------------------------------

This is the ************** JIT Debugging **************

> To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
>       application or computer (machine.config) must have the
>       jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
>       The application must also be compiled with debugging
>       enabled.
>       For example:
>       
>           
>       
>       When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
>       will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
>       rather than be handled by this dialog box.